# how to read full exception stack trace from errorChannel

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to save the exception stack trace to database for some monitoring purpose and i have below configuration but it only prints first line of exception message not the entire stack trace, what i am doing wrong here?

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway 
            id="errorDBLogger"
            data-source="dataSource"
            request-channel="errorChannel" 
            reply-channel="errorSaverepply"
            stored-procedure-name="some_SP "
            ignore-column-meta-data="true">             
            <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition .....parameter mappings..
            <int-jdbc:parameter name="errorMessage" expression="payload"/>                                                  
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

Also i will like default error handling mechanism to remain unaffected as i also have logger configured to email errros which i want to keep as it is, if you could reply in that scenario please.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload is an `Exception` and `Throwable.toString()` only includes the class name and message.

You will need a transformer or header-enricher upstream to convert the payload to the stack trace.

EDIT:

To get the stack trace you have to invoke `Throwable.printStackTrace(pw)`; by default, `Throwable.printStackTreace()` writes to `stderr` so you need to create a `PrintWriter` to pass in.

Something like...

```
private String getStackTraceAsString(Throwable cause) {
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter, true);
    cause.printStackTrace(printWriter);
    return stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, the original SI message whose processing caused exception is available as well?

Comment: Does not look like its there, so the question is how to get it there to make logging more colorful, if you could help please, thanks

Comment: Yes, `payload.cause` is the original exception. Edited the answer with how to extract to a `String`.

Comment: Sorry - misread your question; see `payload.failedMessage`. That is the message at the point of failure. If you want the original input message, you can promote the payload to a header early in the flow using a `<header-enricher/>`.